# Leading zero with custom google sheet format

Tags: google-sheets

I've a question regarding a custom cell format...

This format has to be +0.123 ... + 1.234 ... -0.123 ... -1.234...

I've put this format:

```
[Color9](+#,##.00);[Color10](-#,##.00);(-)
```

Problem is if number is 0.something, as it will appear (-.234) ...

But, if I put

```
[Color9](+0,##.00);[Color10](-0,##.00);(-)
```

it works but, if over +1 or -1, it will appear (+01.234)...

Any idea how to show zero just if between +1 and -1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the # before the dot with a zero:

```
[Color9](+#,#0.00);[Color10](-#,#0.00);(-)
```